# How can i order image files and categorical labels in the same way?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

On the first hand, i have labels, a dataframe with 2 columns : 'image_filename' and 'class_number' in a specific order.

On the other hand, i have a list of image_filename in a different order. I converted it into a list of numpy arrays.

How could i align those two things to make it ready for machine learning ?

Comment: find a something common between these tables and sort them accordingly. are 'image_filename' the same between the two but not sorted the same? if they are, just sort them.

Comment: show proper data https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask